# Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list error

Tags: .net, iis, .net-core

I have a new web server with .net 4.7.2 version 416814 but I get an error when trying to get the site to work. Thanks for your help in advance. I'm not sure how to fix this problem.

Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list.

I installed Webdeploy 6 on the server if that impacts this

I have it working on a different server. I've run .net framework verification setup utility and they all come back fine. I have a separate server that has the same problem and tried to load framework 4.8 to "repair" the installation and it didn't help.
I cleared the asp .net cache and that didn't help

This is in the web.config
remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"

Comment: I suggest you could try to re-register ASP.NET with aspnet_regiis -i. Command like this     c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?